# How to return an int within a trie in python

Tags: python, search, trie

I'm trying to search for a word within my trie data structure and if it exists in the trie, return the word and its frequency.

This is what the trie looks like:

```
{'c': {'u': {'t': {('e', 10): True, ('s', 50): True},
   ('t', 30): True,
   ('b', 15): True},
  'a': {'l': {('m', 1000): True}}},
 'a': {'n': {('t', 20): True,
   'n': {'o': {'t': {'a': {'t': {'i': {'o': {('n', 5): True}}}}}}}},
  'p': {'p': {'l': {('e', 300): True},
    'e': {'n': {'d': {'i': {('x', 10): True}}}},
    ('s', 60): True},
   'o': {'l': {'o': {'g': {('y', 600): True,
       'e': {'t': {'i': {('c', 1000): True}}}}}}}}},
 'f': {'u': {'r': {'t': {'h': {'e': {('r', 40): True}}},
    'n': {'i': {'t': {'u': {'r': {('e', 500): True}}}}}},
   ('r', 10): True},
  'i': {'n': {('d', 400): True}},
  'a': {'r': {('m', 5000): True,
    'm': {'i': {'n': {('g', 1000): True}}, 'e': {('r', 300): True}}},
   't': {'h': {'o': {('m', 40): True}}}}}}
```

Say I'm searching for the word cuts, how would I go about coding that so that I can return its integer pair which in this case is 50?

Btw the True part marks the end of the word.

This is my search function in psedocode format:

```
def search(self, word: str) -> int:

    current = self.root

    if word in current.children:
        return its integer pair if its the end of a word and matches
            
    return 0
```

Here's the Trie class:

```
# Class representing a node in the Trie
```

class TrieNode:

```
def __init__(self, letter=None, frequency=None, is_last=False):
    self.letter = letter            # letter stored at this node
    self.frequency = frequency      # frequency of the word if this letter is the end of a word
    self.is_last = is_last          # True if this letter is the end of a word
    self.children: dict[str, TrieNode] = {}     # a hashtable containing children nodes, key = letter, value = child node

class TrieDictionary(BaseDictionary):

def __init__(self):
    # TO BE IMPLEMENTED
    #setting root to object TrieNode()
    self.root = TrieNode()
```

Basically for the output of my trie I printed out self.root.children

Comment: Could you add the rest of your class definition? The way tuples are keys in these sub-dictionaries seems to kill the purpose of a trie. This is not how it is done. Is this structure set in stone? I would strongly suggest to use a standard trie structure; not this.

Comment: @trincot sorry I've edited the post to provide more clarity. and as this is for homework, i can only add to the functions and cannot change or add anymore

Comment: The design of data structure is not reasonable. Personally, I think frequency can be used as the end. If a letter not only can be used as the end but also can be followed by other letters, a special key can be set in the value dictionary to mark it.

Comment: @MechanicPig yes I now have realised that the reason I'm so lost with this is due to the fact that I built my Trie wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively:

```
def recursive_tree_search(tree, word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        return {k: v for k, v in tree.keys()}[word]
    else:
        subtree = tree[word[0]]
        subword = word[1:]
        return recursive_tree_search(subtree, subword)


example_tree = {
    'c': {
        'u': {
            't': {
                ('e', 10): True, ('s', 50): True}, ('t', 30): True, ('b', 15): True},
        'a': {
            'l': {
                ('m', 1000): True}}},
    'a': {
        'n': {
            ('t', 20): True,
            'n': {
                'o': {
                    't': {
                        'a': {
                            't': {
                                'i': {
                                    'o': {
                                        ('n', 5): True}}}}}}}},
        'p': {
            'p': {
                'l': {
                    ('e', 300): True},
                'e': {
                    'n': {
                        'd': {
                            'i': {
                                ('x', 10): True}}}},
                ('s', 60): True},
            'o': {
                'l': {
                    'o': {
                        'g': {
                            ('y', 600): True,
                            'e': {
                                't': {
                                    'i': {
                                        ('c', 1000): True}}}}}}}}},
    'f': {
        'u': {
            'r': {
                't': {
                    'h': {
                        'e': {
                            ('r', 40): True}}},
                'n': {
                    'i': {
                        't': {
                            'u': {
                                'r': {
                                    ('e', 500): True}}}}}},
            ('r', 10): True},
        'i': {
            'n': {
                ('d', 400): True}},
        'a': {
            'r': {
                ('m', 5000): True,
                'm': {
                    'i': {
                        'n': {
                            ('g', 1000): True}},
                    'e': {
                        ('r', 300): True}}},
            't': {
                'h': {
                    'o': {
                        ('m', 40): True}}}}}}


print(recursive_tree_search(example_tree, "cuts"))
```

Result: `50`

Note: This doesn't have any Error-handling if a key isn't found and things like that. But that should be easy to add.

Trie-Node-class-based version:

```
def search(self, word: str) -> int:
    if len(word) == 1:
        return self.frequency
    else:
        return self.children[word[0]].search(word[1:])
```

No guarantees here, as I can't test this. But something like that should work.

Comment: yes, that problem is that due to me being unallowed to modify the search function and all the other functions and only being able to add, i am unsure of how to implement the search without giving the new tree to the function. 
Is it possible to do this with all the code being contained in the search() function i already provided?

Comment: I added a version using the TrieNode. Possibly you need to change it a bit, but the idea should work. You basically traverse your Nodes recursively returning the frequency for the last node.

Comment: ok, thank you so much for your help. Your answer has highlighted the fact that the way I built my Trie is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary you provide at the start of your question seems to be some output generated from the `TrieDictionary` class, as it doesn't correspond well to that class definition itself: it has no tuples as dictionary keys.

Here is how the `search` method could look:

```
def search(self, word: str) -> int:
    current = self.root
    for ch in word:
        if ch not in current.children:
            return 0  # not found
        current = current.children[ch]
    if current.is_last:
        return current.frequency
    return 0  # it's a proper prefix of a trie-word, but not matching one
```

For completeness sake, I provide here the code that loads the data in the trie using an `insert` method, and then calls the `search` method to retrieve the frequency of the word "cuts":

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self, letter=None, frequency=None, is_last=False):
        self.letter = letter
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.is_last = is_last
        self.children: dict[str, TrieNode] = {}

class TrieDictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()
    
    def insert(self, word, freq=1):
        node = self.root
        for ch in word:
            if not ch in node.children:
                node.children[ch] = TrieNode(ch)
            node = node.children[ch]
        if node.is_last:
            node.frequency += freq
        else:
            node.is_last = True
            node.frequency = freq

    def search(self, word: str) -> int:
        current = self.root
        for ch in word:
            if ch not in current.children:
                return 0  # not found
            current = current.children[ch]
        if current.is_last:
            return current.frequency
        return 0  # it's a proper prefix of a trie-word, but not matching one 

data = [
    ('cute', 10),
    ('cuts', 50),
    ('cut', 30),
    ('cub', 15),
    ('calm', 1000),
    ('ant', 20),
    ('annotation', 5),
    ('apple', 300),
    ('appendix', 10),
    ('apps', 60),
    ('apology', 600),
    ('apologetic', 1000),
    ('further', 40),
    ('furniture', 500),
    ('fur', 10),
    ('find', 400),
    ('farm', 5000),
    ('farming', 1000),
    ('farmer', 300),
    ('fathom', 40)
]

trie = TrieDictionary()
for word, freq in data:
    trie.insert(word, freq)

print(trie.search("cuts"))  # 50
```

### Other remarks

Not your question, but the `TrieNode` class is bloated: it should not need to have a `letter` attribute, as that follows from the character that was selected in the trie to get to that node. It is redundant information. You can see in the proposed `search` implementation that this attribute is never used.

Also, `TrieNode` should not really need the `is_last` attribute: the fact that it is a terminating node is implied by a non-zero frequency.

That `frequency` attribute should always be an `int` (not `None` which currently is its default value). So either `frequency` has a value 0, and then the node is not a terminating node, or it is greater than 0, and then it is a terminating node.

Comment: ok, thank you so much for your help. Your answer has highlighted the fact that the way I built my Trie is wrong.